# Graphing using vector signal analyzer

Tags: signal-processing

I am having trouble trying to create this graph using vector signal analyzer. I am still new to using this device and any help with setting it up would be helpful. The first and second photo are what I have right now and I wish to change it to Trace A: Ch1 FM main time just like the third photo. Also, how do you change the x-axis and y-axis same from the first/second photo to third photo?  [image] [image: Initial][image: final]

Comment: The first rule on using a complex piece of equipment is to read the manual. You should also identify the make and model of your equipment to make it easier to help you.

Comment: @Barry that's a HP 89441A, an older VSA, showing something that's definitely not configured appropriately :)

Answer (score 0):

The measurement in the last picture is in the time domain, whilst the first two are in frequency domain. To have a signal analyzer checking signals in the time domain you have to set the SPAN of the measurement to 0. So, set the center frequency of the measurement to 83.685 kHz and the SPAN to 0 Hz and you should get the measurement you want.